# Entity Framework 6 Too Many EntityTypeConfigurations in DbMigration: StackoverflowException

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

In one of my current projects, we're using EntityFramework 6.1.3 with manual migration. So far, everything worked fine but now we reached the number of 850 EntityTypeConfigurations for a single DbContext. Since then, the creation of the database causes a StackOverflowException in the DbMigration. Unfortunately, I don't see much more information than this exception:

[image: Stackoverflow in DbMigration]

When I remove a couple of EntityTypeConfigurations, it seems to work again. So, technically, I could be splitting the database into different DbContexts or split the DbMigration step into multiple steps. It would work, but it's nasty too.

Does anyone have the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

The answer (afaik) was to split this huge EF context into multiple smaller ones. The first approach was to split the big context into multiple InitialCreates by bundling EF type configurations. This is a very complicated approach and leads to higher complexity if you  need to refresh the logical InitialCreate migration step. A much better approach was to logically split the big EF context: Divide it into multiple smaller, domain-related contexts.